# Line Graph from Dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I've got the following dictionary:

```
adict = {'Females': {'Smoking < 15 Cigarretes': 39.68,
  'Smoking 15 - 25 Cigarretes': 48.52,
  'Smoking > 25 Cigarretes': 11.79},
 'Males': {'Smoking < 15 Cigarretes': 27.21,
  'Smoking 15 - 25 Cigarretes': 51.35,
  'Smoking > 25 Cigarretes': 21.44}}
```

I'm trying to plot a line graph using matplotlib, where I have two lines, one for females and one for males. I'm thinking the x-axis should be the three categories (under 15, 15-25, over 25) and the y-axis should be the values. Does anyone have any advice on how to do it?

I've tried the following code but it only displays Females, and as 3 different lines.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(adict)
df2 = df.transpose()
df2.plot(figsize = (10,8))
plt.show()
```

Comment: What about just `df.plot()`?

Answer (score 0):

For your data, there is no continuous independent variable, but instead a discrete one, which is the number of cigarettes per day, stored as three categories.

I would suggest plotting a bar chart as I have done below:

The main change for me here was creating two `pd.Series` objects dynamically when iterating over 'Males' and 'Females'.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# generate data
data = {
    'Females': {
        'Smoking < 15 Cigarettes': 39.68,
        'Smoking 15 - 25 Cigarettes': 48.52,
        'Smoking > 25 Cigarettes': 11.79
    },
    'Males': {
        'Smoking < 15 Cigarettes': 27.21,
        'Smoking 15 - 25 Cigarettes': 51.35,
        'Smoking > 25 Cigarettes': 21.44
    }
}

# set design parameters
colours = ['red', 'blue']
names = data.keys()

# initialise axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
ax.tick_params(labelsize='x-large')

# iterate over male and female
for i, name in enumerate(names):

    # get data
    series = pd.Series(data[name])

    # set width positive or negative
    if i == 0:
        width = -0.4
    else:
        width = 0.4

    # plot bar
    ax.bar(
        series.index.str.replace('Smoking ', ''),
        series.values,
        color=colours[i],
        label=name,
        width=width,
        align='edge'
    )

# set labels appropriately
ax.set_xlabel('Number of Cigarettes', fontsize='xx-large')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency', fontsize='xx-large')

# add legend
ax.legend(fontsize='x-large', frameon=False)

# save to file
fig.savefig('output.png')
```

[image: Final Plot for Males and Female Smoking Frequency]